# The use of image processing to extract data from a diagram

Tags: java, image-processing, geometry

I have a data flow diagram (a diagram that looks like a flow chart). It has a set of specific geometrical components like rectangles, circles, ellipses and arrows.

What I'm trying to achieve is to detect these shapes and be able to know which component is connected to which component (through the lines) and finally read the text inside each one to extract data from the diagram and do further processing. It is also notable to mention that the diagram will not be drawn by hand but computer generated so we don't have to worry about angles and ratios being inaccurate.

I'm currently working in Java and I was wondering if this is going to be possible since Java is not the best language when it comes to image processing (correct me if I'm wrong). And if it's possible I'd you guys to point out where I should start looking.

Comment: looks like the worst way to do it. Is that some attempt to reverse engineer some legacy documentation?

Comment: Java is OK if your image is not too big but most probably you'll have to implement things by hand. The official image processing library (JAI) is old and nobody cares about it, for some unknown reason. Maybe C++ has better support, but for this task, probably Java is OK

Comment: It's complicated to help you without more detail. Please, provide an example of the input image and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in Java wasn't a great idea because mainly the lack of online resources. After a good amount of research, I found that the best and the easiest approach was the use of C# and [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the OpenCV image processing library.

This [example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp) helped me to get started with detecting basic geometrical shapes like Lines, Rectangles and Triangles.

Answer (score 0):

I think Java is fine, and it has many libraries to process images. ImageJ is just one example. Personally, I like to use Python, so I write scripts in this language using Java API of the [DMelt platform](http://jwork.org/dmelt/). Look at the documentation of this projecst, wiki. Here is [a link](http://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?art=Images/) to a few examples.